# NavigationEnd .subscribing to route.snapshot

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, ngrx

Hi Guys was wondering if you could give me any pointers? I'm currently trying to grab a URL and display a function dynamically.

```
this._mont.showMap(+this._route.snapshot.params['id']));
```

Whenever I use this line of code the showMap() function gets caught on the current index. I'd like to use the NagivationEnd router event to grab the next index.

```
this.router.events.filter((routerEvent) => routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(() => this._mont.showMap(+this._route.snapshot.params['id']));
}
```

I was wondering if I'm going about this correctly or is there a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not an entirely wrong way to do this, I recommend subscribing to the ActivatedRoute: `route.paramMap`. This way, the function only gets called when the id parameter changes, which is more efficient than calling it every time the url changes.
Edit:
You can get the id straight from the subscribe result too (as `result => result.get('id')`). Edit 2: Use the `.get()` method.

Comment: So something along the lines of this?

Comment: this._route.paramMap.
    subscribe((params: ParamMap) =>
    this._mont.showMap(+this._route.snapshot.params['id']));

Comment: More like `this._route.paramMap.subscribe(params => +params.data.get('id'))`